# Is this system of tracking users via Wi-Fi secure?

Tags: authentication, network, wifi

I am trying to make an app which will be used to track the presence of the users in a location, using the Wi-Fi hotspot of the location. The purpose is to know which user was at the location for how long. The scenario is as follows:

(all request-response takes place over an encrypted channel)

1. The location admins create an account for the user. The admins provide the password for this account to the user. The user signs-in using this password.
2. After sign-in, the app receives a session key.
3. The user arrives at the location. The mobile device joins the Wi-Fi network automatically.
4. The app checks the SSID of the current network. If the SSID is "Location's WiFi", the app sends a challenge to the router by encrypting a random number with a public key, whose private pair is owned by the router.
5. The router decrypts the challenge and replies, which signals the app that it is indeed in the location's network.
6. The app sends the session key to the router. The router associates the IP address with this session key.
7. Every minute, the router sends to server the session keys associated with the IP addresses of the devices that are currently on the network, along with a timestamp.
8. At the end of the day, using the data sent by the router, which user was at the location for how long is calculated.

I am not sure if there is a design flaw in this approach. Can this system be fooled? Are there any holes that I should patch?

I would like to know if:

1. The users can trick the system into making that they were at the location for longer or shorter than actual.
2. The identities associated with IP addresses can be spoofed.

Comment: You assume the user connects automatically. Why not use client certificates?  Do you inform the user that they will be physically tracked if they use your app? You don't state what you want this scheme to be secure *from*.

Comment: @schroeder Edited the secure from part. Yes, I inform the users that they will be tracked. I googled for "client certificate" but there is not much on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client_certificate). Are there any sources that you can recommend?

Comment: "wifi client certificate authentication"